# How to output `tkinter` standalone app with `nuitka`?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-poetry, nuitka

I'm trying to wrap my brain around how to output a standalone (`.app`/`.exe`) `tkinter` application with `nuitka`. I do get an output file from `nuitka`, but when I open it, nothing happens (I'm also not sure if it actually uses the `pyproject.toml`). Hopefully someone can shed some light on this - the docs are quite confusing and I haven't found too many good resources yet. Am running on MacOS.

Here's a minimal example. I've created a project with `poetry`;

```
.
├── nuitka_test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── test.py
├── poetry.lock
└── pyproject.toml
```

`__main__.py`:

```py
from test import tk_window
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk_test = tk_window()
    tk_test.run()
```

`test.py`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
class tk_window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
    
    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
```

`pyproject.yaml`:

```yaml
[tool.poetry]
name = "nuitka-test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Some name <some@email.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "nuitka_test"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
nuitka = "^1.5.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "nuitka", "toml"]
build-backend = "nuitka.distutils.Build"

[nuitka]
enable-plugin = "tk-inter"
```

When I run the scripts on their own, they run just fine. I've tried a range of `nuitka` calls, includeing combinations of `--onefile`, `--macos-create-app-bundle`, `--enable-plugin=tk-inter`, such as:

```bash
python -m nuitka --macos-create-app-bundle nuitka_test --enable-plugin=tk-inter -o nuitka_test.app

python -m nuitka --onefile nuitka_test --enable-plugin=tk-inter -o nuitka_test.app
```

Comment: AFAIK, Poetry does not supports Nuitka. What document did you follow to write the ```pyproject.toml```? Anyway, what about just following [the official guide](https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#use-case-1-program-compilation-with-all-modules-embedded)?